# Data Munging: Editing Rows on a Condition

Tags: r

I am looking to edit one of my columns based on information on some other variables. Here is the data and the question underneath:

```
Current Data: 
time_played     Round     Type
NA                1        Pre
10                1        Post
NA                Bye      Pre
NA                Bye      Post
NA                3        Pre
96                3        Post
NA                4        Pre
79                4        Post
```

And I would like to change it to this format:

```
time_played     Round     Type
NA                1        Pre
10                1        Post
10                Bye      Pre
0                 Bye      Post
0                 3        Pre
96                3        Post
96                4        Pre
79                4        Post
```

that is: the "Pre" of a Round is equal to the previous Round's "Post", where Bye is treated like  Round, except its Post will just have 0 time_played

Please let me know how this could be done on R

Thank you very much in advance

Comment: Could you try to explain the desired output a bit more extensive? I don't get the logic.

Answer (score 1):

We can use `fill` from `tidyr`

```
library(tidyverse)
df1 %>%
   mutate(time_played = replace(time_played, Round == "Bye" & 
              Type == "Post", 0)) %>%
   fill(time_played)
#   time_played Round Type
#1          NA     1  Pre
#2          10     1 Post
#3          10   Bye  Pre
#4           0   Bye Post
#5           0     3  Pre
#6          96     3 Post
#7          96     4  Pre
#8          79     4 Post
```

Answer (score 1):

Another (potentially faster) `dplyr` solution:

```
df %>%
  mutate(time_played = ifelse(Type == "Pre" & lag(Type) == "Post", lag(time_played), 
                           ifelse(Round == "Bye" & Type == "Post", 0, time_played)),
         time_played = ifelse(lag(Round) == "Bye" & lag(time_played) == 0, 0, time_played))
```